# Get some part from $uri NGINX

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I'm now learning about location directive on NGINX, then I have requirement to get only some part of $uri.

For example the URL is `http://example.com/2019/10/92/cat/file.mp4`, then on NGINX using $uri will get: `/2019/10/92/cat/file.mp4`. Is there a way to get only some part of the $uri?

My goal is to get dir name with certain depth of level like this: `/2019/10/92/cat` from URL `http://example.com/2019/10/92/cat/file.mp4`

This has to works with any URL, and still produce same depth level of dir:

`http://example.com/2019/10/92/cat/file.mp4` -> `/2019/10/92/cat`
`http://example.com/2019/10/92/cat/cat_2/file.mp4` -> `/2019/10/92/cat`

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should go with regex.

```
location ~* ^/(?<somepartfromuri>.*)/*.mp4 {
      set $myvar ${somepartfromuri};
```

(not tested)